# Context availability on application lifecycle on Android

Tags: android, android-context

If I extend from the Application class and I create a singleton class where my data context is stored (User with Invoices, Invoice with Articles, Articles with Prices, ...). Would this "context" variable be available while the application is alive? Is there a maximum size in memory for this storage?

Comment: Did you find an answer to your question?

Comment: Only yours, so I am using this context I have extended. No news about if there is a maximum size for this storage in teh application.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will be available, and you will be able to obtain it as follows:

```
YourObject obj = getApplication ().someMethod ();
YourObject obj2 = getApplication ().publicObject;
```